# Install Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, system-installation

Is there a possibility to install ubuntu server without asking further questions.

I want to be asked for installation details (username, password, a.s.o.) at the beginning of the installation process, and no more further questions during the rest of installation.

If you have to install several servers a day it is quite annoying to give an answer, wait a minute, give next answer and wait another minute.

I would love to do that at the beginning of installation, and then have time to do some other things.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options

1) You can use [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apbs01.html#preseed-methods)

2) You can use [Kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html)

3) [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit)

If you are familiar with Windows Answer files the first two options will be familiar to you. Option 3 is primarily used in "cloud" environments, but it is possible to generate your own "cloud" image that you just roll out and use CloudInit to configure.

I personally use Kickstart because I deal with more than just Ubuntu servers and it standardizes my installation files.